# Sticky top nav plus element from each section

Tags: jquery, css, layout, responsive-design

I have a design for a new site which features a sticky nav at the top.

No problem there.

Each section has a heading graphic, which is really just a coloured bar. As I scroll down past each seciton, I'd like the coloured bar from that section to stick beneath the nav. So as you're scrolling down, the nav is collecting debris so to speak.

If I have 5 sections, when I'm at the bottom of the page, the nav will have 5 coloured bars beneath it.

Is there an example or plugin that would be this reasonably simple to accomplish?

[image: c]

Comment: While not an immediate solution (due to browser support), it's worth noting that position: sticky; is now a thing. [html5rocks](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I start explaining things, here's a quick little demo that I pumped out, take a look, and then I'll walk you through what I did:

http://jsfiddle.net/4JUaK/1/

```
var bar_positions = [];
$.each($('.bar'), function () {
    bar_positions.push($(this).offset().top);
});
```

First, I made an array to store the positions of the bars by looping through them and adding them in.

```
var collected_bars = 0;
var debris_height = 20;
$(window).scroll(function () {
```

All I've done here is initialize a few variables that I will use later on, and then I created a `scroll()` function which gets fired every time the user scrolls.

```
    var random_number = 0;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + debris_height >= bar_positions[collected_bars]) {
        collected_bars++;
        debris_height += 20;
        random_number = Math.random() * 8 - 4;
        $('.bar' + collected_bars).css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + random_number + 'deg)',
            'transform': 'rotate(' + random_number + 'deg)'
        });
    }
```

This is where it gets fun. The condition checks to see if the `scrollTop()` position - plus whatever extra height for the nav and collected bars - is greater than the position of the nearest bar. The nearest bar is found by looking at the first element in the array, by utilizing the `collected_bars` variable.

If it does exceed that position, I add one to that variable to tell it that we are now going to want to look for the next bar down. Then I add a bit to the `debris_height` to help calculate positions properly for the next one. I also apply the necessary CSS to the bar that we have just "collected". I set it to `position: fixed;`, and since I've already declared the `left` and `top` properties in the stylesheet, that's all it needs to go where I want it. I also threw in a random rotation... This can be animated to make it look cooler, but I'll leave that up to you.

After this block of code is essentially the mirror of version of what we just did... If our position becomes less than that of the previously collected bar, put things back the way they were!

Now, obviously I did this pretty quickly and it's a bit rough, but this should be enough for you to take and clean it up to what it needs to be...

One big thing that I did not cover in my example:

When you change a bar to be in a fixed position, it no longer occupies space in the page, and everything will shift up. In my example I did not do anything to accommodate this, so the positioning comparisons get a little out of synch. The best solution would be to add `padding` or something to fill the space when an element gets taken out of the flow, to prevent a noticeable change. Otherwise you would need to calculate this into the equation somehow.

Hope that helps.. let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thanks. So much appreciated. I need to digest and play with this now. it's an awesome start and seems like a solution even I can understand in terms of the JS. PS I may indeed have further questions but will try  and nut out as much as I can myself.